# How to count following-sibling::*[1][self::disp-quote]

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to count `following-sibling::*[1][self::disp-quote]` position **EXAMPLE** S/B **EXAMPLE 1**

**Input File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sec>
    <title>Title</title>
    <p>vlvvnlfjkvv</p>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <p>aaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaa</p>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <p>vvvkvuvhv</p>
</sec>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sec>
    <title>Title</title>
    <p>vlvvnlfjkvv</p>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE 1</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE 2</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE 3</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <p>aaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaa</p>
    <disp-quote><p content-type="example"><bold>EXAMPLE</bold> aaaaaaa</p></disp-quote>
    <p>vvvkvuvhv</p>
</sec>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <bold aid:cstyle="bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:if test=".='EXAMPLE' and ancestor::disp-quote[following-sibling::*[1][self::disp-quote]]">
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::disp-quote[following-sibling::*[1][self::disp-quote]]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::disp-quote[following-sibling::*[1][self::disp-quote]])+1"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </bold>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit from comments**:

> My Expected result only if it comes disp-quote with comes same
>   following sibling disp-quote then add with position() Example 1,
>   Example 2, Example 3. if its comes single disp-quote then No change
>   only Example.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your requirements, do you want to add a number to `disp-quote/p/b[. = 'Example']` if there are adjacent `disp-quote` siblings? In this case it seems you could use `for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::disp-quote[p/b[. = 'Example']])"`, test whether `current-grouping-key()` is true and then push each member of the group through a mode or templates with a tunnel parameter of the `position()` in the group used further down the hierarchy to number the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Michael's suggestion to use `xsl:number` is the way you want to use as long as you want to number all `<b>EXAMPLE</b>` in any `disp-quote`, even a single one; if you only want to number them if there is more than one `disp-quote` in an adjacent group then the suggestion made in a comment might help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="sec[disp-quote]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::disp-quote[p/bold = 'EXAMPLE'])">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and tail(current-group())">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="number-examples"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="disp-quote" mode="number-examples">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:with-param name="dq-pos" tunnel="yes" select="position()"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="disp-quote/p/bold[. = 'EXAMPLE']">
      <xsl:param name="dq-pos" tunnel="yes" select="()"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="., $dq-pos"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3bW/

Comment: Thanks for reply @Martin Honnen!

Comment: @Sandy, if the the reply solved your problem then you can indicate by accepting the answer, then it is clear the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this very complicated (or perhaps it really is?)

I would do

```
<xsl:template match="disp-quote//bold[.='EXAMPLE']">
  <bold aid:cstyle="bold">
    <xsl:text>EXAMPLE </xsl:text>
    <xsl:number level="any" count="bold" from="sec"/>
  </bold>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think `from="sec/*[not(self::disp-quote)]"` is needed to restart numbering for new "group" of adjacent `disp-quote` elements. At least that is what I think is the aim.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't think I got to the bottom of understanding the requirements. Or perhaps the aim is that EXAMPLEs in a group-of-one don't get numbered. Who knows.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen and Micheal Kay for the reply, but My Expected result only if it comes disp-quote with comes same following sibling disp-quote then add with  position()  **Example 1**, **Example 2**, **Example 3**. if its comes single disp-quote then No change only **Example**. Please can you give me advise?

Comment: You need to express your requirement more clearly. We can't work out what you want to achieve from a single test case, some non-working code, and some unclear prose. (From your latest comment, why is Example 3 numbered?)